# SessionFactory code in Hiberante is not executing/proceeding

Tags: java, hibernate

Following is my java class. I am using Hibernate 5.2.11 with jdk1.8. Even I tried with other 5.2.x versions but still my program just exits from very first line of code always( mentioned in class ).

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateCfg {

// private static final Logger logger =
// LogManager.getLogger(HibernateCfg.class.getName());

private static HibernateCfg hc = null;
private static final Object object = new Object();
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private StandardServiceRegistry registry;
private Session session;

private HibernateCfg() {

    sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
    // Create registry

}

private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    try {
//code stops here at below line
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        return sessionFactory;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;

}

public static HibernateCfg getObject() {
    if (hc == null) {
        synchronized (object) {
            if (hc == null) {
                hc = new HibernateCfg();
            }
        }

    }
    return hc;
}
```

[image]

What seems to be the problem ?

Comment: I suspect this line: `StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml").build();` is throwing an exception but you have an **empty** catch block there so you have no idea what that exception is. Log the exception or debug your application then step into that catch block and you'll start to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: No i already did debugging that is how I came to know that after that particular line code just exits.

Comment: Yes you were correct , some jars were missing. Now it is working fine . thank you